# What is the Latest Version of Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I don't know if I can use Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC within Visual Studio 2015. What is the latest version of Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check here on Telerik Website
http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/aspnet-mvc/release-history

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing (31st of May 2016) it is Q2 2016 (2016.2.504) and it works in VS 2015.